# need assistance with dhcpd.conf understanding

Tags: dhcp

How can I interpret the following:

```
class "blade-1-01-1" {
            match if substring (option dhcp-client-identifier, 9, 1) = 01 and
                     substring (option dhcp-client-identifier, 5, 1) = 01 and
                     substring (option dhcp-client-identifier, 6, 1) = 00;
        }
```

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a section establishing a client class called `blade-1-01-1` as being defined by those portions of the client identifier string in the client's DHCPDISCOVER packet.

The client identifier is used to identify the DHCP client that's doing the request. So for example, if you're dual booting between Windows and Linux, you'll have the same MAC address but two different identifier strings.

`dhcpd` classes can be used to set particular options, set lease limitations, tie them to particular address pools, etc.

If your question is about the `substring` function [you can check the dhcp-eval manpage](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/dhcp-eval.5.php):

> substring (data-expr, offset, length)
>
> The substring operator evaluates the data expression and returns the
>   substring of the result of that evaluation that starts offset bytes
>   from the beginning, continuing for length bytes. Offset and length are
>   both numeric expressions. If data-expr, offset or length evaluate to
>   null, then the result is also null. If offset is greater than or equal
>   to the length of the evaluated data, then a zero-length data string is
>   returned. If length is greater then the remaining length of the
>   evaluated data after offset, then a data string containing all data
>   from offset to the end of the evaluated data is returned.